# Google Mock - Test returns without result when using CoTaskMemFree

Tags: c++, unit-testing, winapi, googlemock

I have a method in a class that cleans up memory using CoTaskMemFree:

```
HRESULT A::doStuff() {
    PWSTR protectedPassword = L"";
    HRESULT hr = helper->ProtectMyPassword(L"Secret", &protectedPassword);
    LOG("Before CoTaskMemFree");
    CoTaskMemFree(protectedPassword);
    LOG("After CoTaskMemFree");
    return hr;
}
```

I want to test that the method ProtectMyPassword is called, so I mocked my Helper-class and wrote the following test:

```
TEST(TestA, MyTest)
{
    // arrange
    NiceMock<HelperMock> helperMock;
    A classUnderTest = A(&helperMock);
    PWSTR password = L"SuperSecretPwd";
    EXPECT_CALL(helperMock, ProtectMyPassword (_, _)).WillByDefault(DoAll(SetArgPointee<2>(password), Return(1)));

    // act
    HRESULT hr = classUnderTest.doStuff();

    // assert
    EXPECT_TRUE(SUCCEEDED(hr));
}
```

However if I run the test it shows "RUN" but not "OK" and finishes without any error.

```
[ RUN      ] TestA.SomeOtherTest
[       OK ] TestA.SomeOtherTest (2 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestA.MyTest

D:\Projects\PwdSafe\C++\x64\Release>
```

In my log I see "Before CoTaskMemFree" but not "After CoTaskMemFree". I'm sure it is something trivial I don't see, but I just cannot work it out.
Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoTaskMemFree` is used to free memory allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc` or `CoTaskMemRealloc`. It will fail when that is not the case.

Your mock is yielding a pointer that does not meet this condition.

```
PWSTR password = L"SuperSecretPwd";
```

Hence the runtime error. In order to fix this you'd need your mock to allocate from the COM heap.

Comment: Indeed, they are passing a static string: `PWSTR password = L"SuperSecretPwd";`. The `EXPECT_CALL()` macro seems to synthesize a function call that just sets the out parameter to that pointer and returns 1.